# Is it safe to extend a Windows API structure?

Tags: c++, winapi

I learned that in Strict mode Windows Handles, like HBRUSH, are defined as a struct to avoid silly mistakes and I was wondering if doing something like the following is safe:

```
class WINBRUSH : public HBRUSH
```

Now I'm not very proficient in C++ but it just seems like a really bad idea. What I was thinking was that because Windows allocates these objects if I don't add anything to the class I should be fine. An example being:

```
class WINBRUSH : public HBRUSH__
{
 public:
    void GetRGB(BYTE* RgbArray)
    {
      LOGBRUSH LogBrush;
      GetObject(this,sizeof(LOGBRUSH),&LogBrush);
      RgbArray[0] = GetRValue(LogBrush.lbColor);
      RgbArray[1] = GetGValue(LogBrush.lbColor);
      RgbArray[2] = GetBValue(LogBrush.lbColor);
    }
};
```

Now I have tested the above class and checked to see if I got the correct values from the GetRGB method and it worked but I just would like some input on this. Thanks in advance, Damon.

Test Code:

```
WINBRUSH* Brush = (WINBRUSH*)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(1,2,3));

BYTE Rgb[3];
Brush->GetRGB(Rgb);

if((Rgb[0] == 1) && (Rgb[1] == 2) && (Rgb[2] == 3))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"RGB values are correct!", L"Success!", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(WINBRUSH) == sizeof(HBRUSH))`

Comment: Thanks, I tested the above code and no error was produced so I'm gonna assume that means its ok.

Comment: Never assume something is OK just because no error is produced. Undefined behavior is undefined; a valid implementation of undefined is works for you and all your colleagues and blows up in your most important customers' face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be safe; it's no different than what happens if you have:

```
struct X
{
    HBRUSH abc;
    GetRGB(/* ... */) {}
}
```

That said, IMHO this is being tricky for the sake of being tricky, and a nonmember function `void GetRGB(HBRUSH h, BYTE* result)` would be clearer and more resistant to breakage with future versions of the SDK. `a.GetRGB(b)` isn't significantly clearer than `GetRGB(a, b)`.

If you do decide to do this make sure you add a `static_assert` so that if someone later tries to add a member variable or something that it fails to compile)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try and change the my methods, I definitely don't want my app breaking-down in the future.